# KEDA scaledjob is not showing the stability

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, persistent-volumes, keda

Configured below KEDA scaledjob in AKS for setting up the container based azuredevops agent. But here some misconfigurations making my system with lot of pod unexpected errors

Since I used the Azuredisk as PV for my Build tools cache, I could optimize the hosting nodes storage for a limit. But the major problem what  i am facing are below.

- Still the work space of my setup is poininting to /azp/_work of the pod which is storing the data localy within the node and when multiple jobs are executed, its fully using the nodes ephemeral storage and getting in errror which is causing the pipeline in not responding state and not picking any available agents.
- Any way to set the workspace directory of the pod also to the PV Azure disk ?
- What is the property in KEDA "  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1"  and  "  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 8" is meant for
  in which threshold an existing scaledjob will be terminated and a new scaledjob pod will be created?

  ```
  apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
   kind: ScaledJob
   metadata:
     name: azdevops-scaledjob
     namespace: ado
   spec:
     failedJobsHistoryLimit: 8
     jobTargetRef:
       template:
         spec:
           affinity:
             nodeAffinity:
               preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
               - preference:
                   matchExpressions:
                   - key: kubernetes.azure.com/mode
                     operator: In
                     values:
                     - mypool
                   - key: topology.disk.csi.azure.com/zone
                     operator: In
                     values:
                     - westeurope-1
                 weight: 2
           containers:
           - env:
             - name: AZP_URL
               value: https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
             - name: AZP_TOKEN
               value: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
             - name: AZP_POOL
               value: az-dev-spoke
             image: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
             imagePullPolicy: Always
             name: azdevops-agent-job
             resources:
               limits:
                 cpu: 1500m
                 memory: 7Gi
               requests:
                 cpu: 500m
                 memory: 4Gi
             securityContext:
               allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
               privileged: true
             volumeMounts:
             - mountPath: /mnt
               name: ado-cache-storage
           volumes:
           - name: ado-cache-storage
             persistentVolumeClaim:
               claimName: azure-disk-pvc
     maxReplicaCount: 8
     minReplicaCount: 1
     pollingInterval: 30
     rollout: {}
     scalingStrategy:
       strategy: default
     successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
     triggers:
     - metadata:
         organizationURLFromEnv: AZP_URL
         personalAccessTokenFromEnv: AZP_TOKEN
         poolID: "xx"
       type: azure-pipelines
  ```